# LinqPad weird behavior when executing .ToArray()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linqpad

This might be a really dumb question, but need to ask this and know why.

I am trying to query an odata web service which according to my query it should give me a response of 400K ish records. This quantity I get it by executing

```
Movies.Where(qry => qry.DeliveryOptions.Any(b => (b.DeliveryType.Contains("digital")) )).Count()
```

This will give me the result of 401560.

But then I do the next line of code

```
Movies.Where(qry => qry.DeliveryOptions.Any(b => (b.DeliveryType.Contains("digital")) )).ToArray().Count()
```

This now gives me the response of 500.

This does now make any sense, why does LinqPad is limiting the conversion to array to 500?

Comment: ToArray is perhaps forcing full population from the source, what happens in VS?

Comment: I guess the first `Count()` is `Queryable.Count()` and the second is (definitely) `Enumerable.Count()`. It means that the first one is generating a SQL `COUNT` statement that is evaluated in the data source (probably SQL Server) while the second `Count()` is somehow limited by some LinqPad-imposed rule

Comment: Also, check "Preferences" > "Results" in LinqPad menu

Comment: Is the server limiting the number of records returned? see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#server-paging

Comment: Can you check the generated sql in sql tab in Linqpad? What does it says?

Comment: I discovered this, our server is throttling the resultset. Thank you